# Find by integrating the area of ​​the triangle vertices $(5,1), (1,3)\;\text{and}\;(-1,-2)$

Tags: calculus, geometry, integration, definite-integrals

> Find by integrating the area of ​​the triangle vertices $$(5,1), (1,3)\;\text{and}\;(-1,-2)$$

I tried to make straight and integrate, but it is very complicated, there is some better way?

Comment: Hint: Can you find the equations of the three lines and then figure out how to integrate the pairs of them to find the area? An easier approach is to surround the triangle with the smallest possible rectangle whose sides are parallel to the axes. This has corners at (-1, -2), (-1, 3), (5, 3), (5, -2). You can easily find the area of that rectangle. Then find the area of the three right-angled triangles which have to be removed to leave the area of the triangle that you want.

Comment: @Amzoti This will give a workforce a little big ... But I'll try ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just tedious.

Let $f_1(x) = \frac{5x+1}{2}$, $f_2(x) = \frac{7-x}{2}$, $f_3(x)= \frac{x-3}{2}$.

$(-1,f_1(-1)) = (-1,f_3(-1)) = (-1,-2)$,

$(1,f_1(1)) = (1,f_2(1)) = (1,3)$,

$(5,f_2(5)) = (5, f_3(5)) = (5, 1)$.

$A = \int_{-1}^1 (f_1(x)-f_3(x) ) dx + \int_{1}^5 (f_2(x)-f_3(x) ) dx = 4 +8 = 12$.

Comment: Amazing, congratulations, but could give better detail and edit 3rd to 5th line?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Lines 3-5 just show that $f_i$ are straight lines joining the given points. If you draw the points (or check above) you will see that $f_1(x) \ge f_3(x)$ on $[-1,1]$ and $f_2(x) \ge f_3(x)$ on $[1,5]$. The rest is just grind.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Call $A$, $B$ and $C$ the vertices of the triangle.  It's area is then
$$\frac 12 |\det(C-A, C-B)|.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
{1 \over 2}\left\{%
\left[5\times 3 - 1\times 1\right]
+
\left[1\times\left(-2\right) - 3\times\left(-1\right)\right]
+
\left[\left(-1\right)\times 1 - 5\times\left(-2\right)\right]\right\}
=
{14 + 1 + 9 \over 2}
=
\color{#ff0000}{\Large 12}
$$

Answer (score -1):

You can try to simplify the calculations by using 1. Shift of origin ( say to (-1,-2) ), and 2. Rotation of axis. Then do the integrations.

Comment: Why the downvote?